# PHP SDK not giving id back

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I was using the following code on a Facebook canvas application  to get the user ID. It was working till tonight, and now it gives me "0".
What could I do differently?

```
require_once("facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = '***';
$config[‘secret’] = '****';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$userid = $facebook->getUser();

echo $userid;
```

Comment: look for another script maybe or read and try to do it yourself with reading docs of facebook api ?

Comment: Looks good, as long as your require_once and config array items are correct.  Is there more to the story?

Comment: Btw, this is the expected result if the user is not connected to your app.

Comment: Today this started happening to me too. I had previously been using the sdk for many months.

Answer (score 0):

If the user isn't logged *in to your app* via getLoginUrl or otherwise, you will always get 0.

Also consider updating your SDK to the lastest version https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/